# Notebook overheating and system hangs - ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, drivers, overheating, fan, ubuntu-drivers

I installed ubuntu 14.04.2 and my notebooks overheats really fast and sometimes hangs(freezes) - no response at all , so I just have to shutdown manually.

Here's the result of some commands I found in related topics , but they don't tell me much . Please help me

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor sysctl -n vm.laptop_mode
     1  performance
     2  performance
     3  performance
     4  performance
cat: sysctl: No such file or directory
```

installed lm-sensors:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors

sudo sensors-detect
```

entered YES for everything => executed sensors :

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +64.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +64.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +63.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
65000
```

Graphics driver information:

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108M [GeForce GT 540M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:55 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:d1000000-d107ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:d1400000-d17fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```